# Plot of Ori and the Blind Forest

Tags: ori-and-the-blind-forest

Spoilers follow - after beating the wind challenge:

> The spirit tree tries to summon Ori home, but fails. The light kills Kuro's 3 baby owls, which is why she stole the tree's light.
>
>  Why did the summoning light kill the baby owls?

Answer (score 0):

It didn't intentionally kill the chicks of Kuro. There was a ceremony, as the spirit tree released the light, it inadvertently was killing the chicks.

Comment: I get that it wasn't intentional, but why would a bright light kill owls? I mean: if it had coaxed them off the cliff edge or something, but it didn't - they died in their next just by looking at it. What is it about the light that killed the owls?

Comment: Well it's not like it is just a bright light. In the story it represents something more. This is a fantasy world, obviously things are different than our world. It is all symbolic. Perhaps its the simple battle of light and dark and they could live in harmony but it accidentally hurt the owls, which represents dark; causing Kuro to freak out. Ori in Hebrew means "light" or "my light" Kuro in Japanese means "dark"

Answer (score 0):

And also you don't know, in this fantasy world, how creatures of darkness react to light. It could be the same with deep sea fish that are brought to the surface ... they die. First I thought they died of fear, with the light crawling towards them and them with no possibility to escape, but when Kuro sacrifices herself to save her last egg, she is also killed by the light.